# Python SQLITE substituted query returns nothing from database

Tags: python, select, flask, sqlite

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
sqlite> select * from history where timeStamp >= "2016-09-15 13:05:00" and timeStamp < "2016-09-15 13:06:00";
timeStamp            isOpen    
-------------------  ----------
2016-09-15 13:05:04  0         
2016-09-15 13:05:09  0         
2016-09-15 13:05:14  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:19  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:24  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:29  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:34  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:39  0         
2016-09-15 13:05:44  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:49  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:54  1         
2016-09-15 13:05:59  0
```

From Postman I run: `{{origin}}:{{port}}/logs?from=201609151305&to=201609151306`

In Python, I translate those values to: `2016/09/15 13:05:00` and 
`2016/09/15 13:06:00`, which are passed to my helper method:

```
vals = (lowStr, upperStr)
query = 'select * from history where timeStamp >= ? and timeStamp < ?'
returnList = accessDB('SELECT',query,vals)
```

AccessDB then does the following:

```
def accessDB(operation, query, vals):
    con = None
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('logs.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, vals)
        if operation == 'SELECT':
            return cur.fetchall()
        if operation == 'INSERT':
            con.commit()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Error %s:" % e.args[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

Nothing is being returned in the results, however. The return list is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure SQLite can understand those date formats? They don't match the format used in your raw query.

Comment: Well...that's an embarrassment. Thanks for catching that. You should go ahead and post an answer. Related question: Is there a way to view the raw query that is generated from the cursor.execute method? Like SQL's .last_executed, for instance.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your related question is about. Your query is contained in your `query` variable. Are you looking for something more than that?

Comment: I was just worried that cursor.execute may have done something to the final string that it will send to SQLITE. I want to see what that is (for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example SQL, you are using datetimes with the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

In your Python example, however, you are using datetimes with the format

```
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
```

SQLite isn't seeing this as a valid date format. Change your `/`s to `-`s (how to do that depends on how you're doing the formatting).